# Remote discovery/inventory of attached disk enclosures

Tags: linux, windows, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a handful of HP DL3xx G7 servers, that I know have HP D2600 disk units attached via P411 SmartArray controllers.

I can see info about the array controllers and the disks (via the Array Configuration Utility and the System Management Homepage); I can use various OS tools to see the on-board devices (e.g. by Windows Device Manager, WMI; or Linux `lshal`); I can see the volumes (Windows Device Manager/Disk Management; Linux `fdisk`) but nothing about the physical enclosures, themselves.

I was really just trying to answer some basic questions (e.g. the serial numbers of the enclosures) without having to go to the data centre.

The servers are running a RHEL-based Linux and I just thought it was my own lack of understanding of Linux, but I also can't seem to discover these in Windows either.

Am I going mad?  Blind?  Or can you really not remotely or programatically retrieve information about such devices attached to your server?

Comment: What are your other basic questions? The `hpacucli` utility provides most of the information people need for support purposes.

Comment: @ewwhite - Usual stuff; model, serial, firmware -- What do you know?! it *is* in the ACU (Windows GUI: in enclosure view; Linux: `hpacucli`, then `ctrl slot=*n* enc all show detail` did it for me.  I just found it strange that it wouldn't be something 'visible' to the OS HAL -- if it can see a tape library as a 'medium changer' why not a disk enclosure?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved entirely through the HP System Management Tools. You'll need the [**Array Configuration Utility**](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/) in either its graphical (web) or command line forms (hpacucli).

Here's the output from an [HP Storageworks D2700 enclosure](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/disk-enclosures/product-detail.html?oid=3954790#!tab=features) connected to a Smart Array P812 RAID controller. Note that port WWID's, HP product numbers and serial numbers are included in the output.

```
=> controller slot=1 enclosure all show detail

Smart Array P812 in Slot 1

   StorageWorks D2700 at Port 1E, Box 1, OK
      Fan Status: OK
      Temperature Status: OK
      Power Supply Status: Redundant
      Vendor ID: HP      
      Serial Number: 5C7147P1KT
      Firmware Version: 0147
      Drive Bays: 25
      Port: 1E
      Box: 1
      Location: External
      Standby Path: 2E:1, OK
      Active Path: 1E:1, OK

   Expander 246
      Device Number: 246
      Firmware Version: 0147
      WWID: 5001438016BEF27D
      Port: 1E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP      

   Expander 247
      Device Number: 247
      Firmware Version: 0147
      WWID: 5001438016BEF27F
      Port: 2E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP      

   Enclosure SEP (Vendor ID HP, Model D2700 SAS AJ941A) 244
      Device Number: 244
      Firmware Version: 0147
      WWID: 5001438016BEF27C
      Port: 1E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP      
      Model: D2700 SAS AJ941A

   Enclosure SEP (Vendor ID HP, Model D2700 SAS AJ941A) 245
      Device Number: 245
      Firmware Version: 0147
      WWID: 5001438016BEF27E
      Port: 2E
      Box: 1
      Vendor ID: HP      
      Model: D2700 SAS AJ941A

   Physical Drives
      physicaldrive 1E:1:1 (port 1E:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:2 (port 1E:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:3 (port 1E:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:4 (port 1E:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:5 (port 1E:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:6 (port 1E:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:7 (port 1E:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:8 (port 1E:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:9 (port 1E:box 1:bay 9, SAS, 146 GB, OK, spare)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:10 (port 1E:box 1:bay 10, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:11 (port 1E:box 1:bay 11, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:12 (port 1E:box 1:bay 12, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:13 (port 1E:box 1:bay 13, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:14 (port 1E:box 1:bay 14, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:15 (port 1E:box 1:bay 15, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:16 (port 1E:box 1:bay 16, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:17 (port 1E:box 1:bay 17, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:18 (port 1E:box 1:bay 18, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:19 (port 1E:box 1:bay 19, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:20 (port 1E:box 1:bay 20, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:21 (port 1E:box 1:bay 21, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:22 (port 1E:box 1:bay 22, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:23 (port 1E:box 1:bay 23, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:24 (port 1E:box 1:bay 24, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1E:1:25 (port 1E:box 1:bay 25, SAS, 300 GB, OK)
```

Comment: This does, indeed, solve the problem I was having (and I will very likely be marking it as the answer), but I was particularly interested as to why the enclosures aren't acknowledged by the operating systems.  A similar example might be an HP MSL Tape Library -- which also plugs into a P411 -- is identified by the OS as a Medium Changer, but the disk enclosure is effectively invisible.  It just seems odd that I can use (for example) WMI to tell me the make and model of a RAM stick in the third socket from the left, but I can't see that there is an additional SAS backplane hanging off the back!

Comment: This is because they're specialized devices with their own driver and management layer. Your tape drive/changer speaks SCSI, and that's native to the OS. You can't get HP fan speed and disk array info without these drivers either.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough HP kit it's well worth implementing their ['System Insight Manager'](http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/index.html?jumpid=go/hpsim) (SIM), it does far more than inventory management but it does that job very well - in fact it does that for us on over a hundred thousand devices and it's free!

Comment: But will it provide SAS enclosure serial numbers?

Comment: I don't know for a FACT, I'm not on my work laptop, but I'm reasonably sure yes, well if the agents/ACU are install obviously.